# Updating df, remove my original row.names

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to generate a heat-map in R. To achieve that goal, I need to perform a clustering process and then associate the metadata to a new df that allow me to annotate the heat-map.

I have this lines of code:

```
hclust_col <- cutree(tree = as.dendrogram(hclust_cyto), k = 2)
```

Where the output is:

```
op1 2020 G4 op104 2020 G4 op105 2020 G4 op106 2020 G4  op18 2020 G4   op2 2020 G4 
            1             1             2             1             1             2
```

Then, I can create a df that allow me to associate the information of each cluster:

```
my_gene_col <- data.frame(cluster = ifelse(test = my_gene_col == 1, 
                                           yes = "cluster 1", no = "cluster 2"))
```

Where the output is:

```
op1 2020 G4 cluster 1
op104 2020 G4 cluster 1
op105 2020 G4 cluster 1
```

Now, I tried to perform a `k = 4 or more`, all is good, however, when I try to create a new df with the information of each cluster, I need to change my code to assign the cluster to each row automatically. To achieve that:

```
hclust_col_1 <- data.frame(cluster = paste("cluster", hclust_col))
```

Here is my issue, because this approach remove my original `row.names`:

```
1 cluster 1
2 cluster 1
3 cluster 1
```

In this step I'm losing my original row.names. My questions is:

- What I'm doing wrong?
- How can I keep the row.names?

Comment: Don't create a new data.frame. Row names are a properly of the data.frame itself, not any particular column. If you create a new data.frame, it won;t have any rownames.  Try `transform` to keep rownames, like `hclust_col_1 <- transform(my_gene_col, cluster = paste("cluster", hclust_col))`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paste` function strips off the attributes from the vector.  You need to use the `row.names` argument in `data.frame` function to pass in the rownames:

```
data.frame(cluster = paste("cluster", hclust_col), row.names = names(hclust_col))

                cluster
op1 2020 G4   cluster 1
op104 2020 G4 cluster 1
op105 2020 G4 cluster 2
op106 2020 G4 cluster 1
op18 2020 G4  cluster 1
op2 2020 G4   cluster 2
```